# Car won't start without a jump

Tags: engine, battery, alternator, kia, sedona

Kia Sedona 2004. Battery was corroded. Car died. Replaced battery. Car started only after jumped, but died very soon. Battery wont keep a charge. When it does start, headlights and gauges won't work. Won't take charge and only starts after jump.

Answer (score 3):

Give the car a jump start, but let the leads from the donor vehicle stay on the new battery for a period of time. Check the battery to ensure there is sufficient charge in it (at least 12vdc) to keep the vehicle running. Get the Sedona started and then pull the leads from the donor vehicle. Check the voltage at the battery. If the voltage continues to drop at a slow pace while it's running, the alternator is most likely bad. Pull it from the vehicle, take it down to the parts store and get it checked.

Also, ensure the battery posts and leads are completely free of corrosion. If it isn't, the battery won't charge. Your issue lies in the fact the battery, whether completely new or the old one, is not getting charged. It is either the alternator not charging it, or there's no way for the charge to get to the battery.

Comment: If the headlights etc don't work *even when the engine is running after a jump start*, that is a very clear indication the alternator isn't working. Most of the time tThe alternator

Answer (score 0):

i just replaced my alternator as i had a similiar problem, would firstly recommend checking all leads to and from the battery for any connection issues, as the previous corrosion from the battery may have damaged leads too, then get a mechanic to check your battery voltage, this will tell you if your alternator is in fact charging your battery, it really is as simple as that.
good luck

Answer (score 0):

> Battery was corroded...replaced battery

Did you clean the wires' connectors to the battery? Replacement battery is new, or used and serviced and charged? Connections needs to be pristine! Battery should be >12VDC

> Car started only after jumped, but died very soon

This is common when the engine is running with battery current, instead of battery/alternator pair supplying the current. Could mean a faulting current regulator in the alternator, or the alternator itself.

> Battery wont keep a charge.

Can you try charging the battery with an external charger, and measure it gets 13 ~ 13.5VDC? This may not be a good test to decide if the battery is good (current may drop a lot if the battery is bad), but at least will tell you the battery has some juice.

On the other hand: if the current regulator or alternator is in fault, the battery won't get properly charged. Besides, if the battery is low in charge, it needs some time to get charged. Cranking and testing the engine won't supply enough time to charge it to normal operational level.

> When it does start, headlights and gauges won't work. Won't take
>   charge and only starts after jump.

IMHO, the alternator is faulting or at least the current regulator is not working: your engine is running on battery, the jumping would be adding some little power to it, enough to crank once, but after the engine is running, no power is being supplied to it by the alternator, and in the contrary, the engine is sucking the little power it got by using it for sparks.

My suggestion: charge battery externally and give it a try. If it stills does the joke: check alternator output, check alternator belt is not slipping.

One way to test if alternator is charging: once running the engine: turn on all lights and high beam...if the alternator is good, the engine will still running, if alternator is bad, the load will deplete the battery stalling the engine :) Source? A lot of headache last year with an alternator having intermittent faults!